# Update: How do I dynamically populate a list with data from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, html-lists

I want to dynamically populate a list with elements from a JSON file. The idea is to switch the **test_ID** in the list with the actual object from the JSON file. How do I do this?

**JSON file**

```
 [
   {
     "id": "a",
     "test": "Java",
     "testDate": "2016-08-01"
   },
   {
     "id": "b",
     "test":"JavaScript",
     "testDate": "2016-08-01"
   }
 ]
```

**jQuery**

```
 $(function(){

  $.ajax({
    type : 'GET',
    url : 'json/data.json',
    async : false,
    beforeSend : function(){/*loading*/},
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(result) {
  });

            $("#test_ID").empty(); //emtpy the UL before starting
            $.each(arr_json, function(i, v, d) {
             $("#test_ID").append("<li id='" + v.id +'" + v.test +"' >" + v.testDate + "<li>");
        });
    }
   });
 });
```

**HTML**

```
 <li id="test_ID"></li>
```

I do receive a couple of errors. The Line:

```
$("#test_ID").append("<li id='" + v.id +'" + v.test +"' >" + v.testDate + "<li>");
```

gives the following error: invalid number of arguments and unclosed String literal. 
I am also unsure of how to identify to specific elements in the JSON file.

**Update**
I would like if the list element was in this format "Java 2016-08-01" and "JavaScript 2016-08-01". Thank you!

Comment: 1.  $.each( isn't closed.  You need a closing curly brace and paren. 2. you haven't declared arr_json.  It should be data

Comment: Changed `"<li id='" + v.id +'" + v.test +"' >" + v.testDate + "<li>"` to `"<li id="' + v.id +"' + v.test + '" >' + v.testDate + '<li>'` and try again. You had mismatched quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of errors in your javascript. See the corrected version below:

```
 $(function(){
   $.ajax({
     type : 'GET',
     url : 'json/data.json',
     async : false,
     beforeSend : function(){/*loading*/},
     dataType : 'json',
     success : function(result) {
            $("#test_ID").empty(); //emtpy the UL before starting

            // **************** correction made to the line below ***********************
            $.each(result, function(i, v, d) {                        

            // **************** correction made to the line below ***********************
            $("#test_ID").append('<li id="' + v.id + '">' + v.test + '  ' + v.testDate + '</li>');                         // correction made here
        });
    }
   });
 });
```

Comment: This works great! But how fo I do if I want the format of the list element to look like this: "Java 2016-08-01" and "JavaScript 2016-08-012?

Comment: Thank you so much artemisian for taking a part of your valuable time to help me!

Answer (score 2):

I did a quick fiddle. I don't quite understand what you're doing with v.test being unmarked inside the HTML tags so I did not include it. I used minimal JQuery to avoid complexity.

https://jsfiddle.net/ndx5da97/

```
  for (record in data) {
    $("#test_ID").append('<li id="' + data[record].id + '">' + data[record].testDate + '</li>');
  }
```

Hope this helps!